# Convert LibreOffice Impress exported flash file into mp4 format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I need to export the LibreOffice impress presentation into a video format using python.

I have managed to export the presentation into **flash** file format using pyuno and I need to convert it into mp4 (or any other famous video) format. I have tried using "ffmpeg" but doesn't work.

```
failed to read the duration of file /home/ankur/Desktop/test_dev_1010_v111.swf.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x52f5240] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[swf @ 0x52f3b40] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffdb41d6e70] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[swf @ 0x52f3b40] invalid frame size 0x0
Input #0, swf, from '/home/ankur/Desktop/test_dev_1010_v111.swf':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1058x794 [SAR 96:96 DAR 529:397], 12 tbr, 12 tbn
At least one output file must be specified
```

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: It says it right there. You should put the output file of your choice in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Depending your distribution, you should install a swf parser/reader from packages or from source. [Gnu Gnash](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash) seems to be one.
Debian had packages for stretch but they don't exist anymore for buster. They also provided [python-gtk-gnash](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-gtk-gnash) for python bindings.
How to convert was [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194270/convert-compressed-swf-to-mp4) a long time ago.